# SQL two date range with specific "DAY" in range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

This is my QUERY

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableNAME
WHERE 
st.column_date BETWEEN '" . $_SESSION['selectYear'] . "-" . str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "-11 00:00:00' AND '" . $_SESSION['selectYear'] . "-" . str_pad(($i + 1), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . "-10 23:59:59'
```

This query will bring up the issue when it come to the month 'DECEMBER'.
Looking for help.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and provide clear information on what you want to do.

Comment: seems like issue with `str_pad(($i + 1)`

Comment: MySQL does not seem to have problems with the absence of leading zeroes - you can safely skip the padding.

Comment: Wbat's the value of `$i`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$i` is a month number.  It looks like you want this query, for example if `$i` were 7.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tableNAME
 WHERE st.column_date BETWEEN '2019-07-11 00:00:00' 
                          AND '2019-08-10 23:59:59';
```

Your way of specifying this date range fails over the end of a year, as you have discovered.

What will work for you is this query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tableNAME
 WHERE st.column_date >= '2019-07-11' 
   AND st.column_date <  '2019-07-11' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

- Give the same date parameter twice.
- You don't need to specify the time when it's 00:00.
- Use `+ INTERVAL 1 MONTH` to get the end date. That works correctly over ends of years. It also happens to work correctly for months like February, even in leap years, and even if your start date is something like `2020-01-30`.
- Instead of  `<=  ... 23:59` use `<` and the day *after* the last day
  you want to consider.